# Regular Expression to find the exact match of the string

Tags: python, regex

Hi I have records like

```
MicroAlgae 7.5
AlgaeSerum 6.5
Algae 1.5
```

Here i need to extract the value of algae that is 1.5 and it should not extract the values of microalgae and algaeserum. I have used the regex as

```
/(?!Micro)/Algae,
Algae\s*/^(!Serum)/,
\\bAlgae\\b
```

Kindly let me know how can I write the regex according to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some large text where you need to pull the number from, you may use a simple regex with a capturing group around the part you need to extract:

```
import re
s = """MicroAlgae 7.5
AlgaeSerum 6.5
Algae 1.5"""
m = re.search(r'\bAlgae\s+([0-9.]+)', s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yeRrV2)

The `[0-9.]+` may be replaced with a more precise `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?`.

**Details**:

- `\b`  - the leading word boundary
- `Algae` - the literal char sequence `Algae`
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `([0-9.]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits or dots or
- `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?` - 1+ digits (`[0-9]+`), followed with an optional sequence of a `.` (`\.`) and 1+ digits (`[0-9]+`).